# C/C++ VS Code - Unable to start debugging. There was an error starting the pipe program

Tags: c++, c, bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am learning the Visual Studio Code C/C++ Debugging Tool and I was following the tutorial [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_set-wsl-as-the-default-terminal-optional) and when I go to start the deubbing. I am given this error.

[image]

I am running WSL/Bash on Ubuntu and I installed gcc/g++ and gdb on the WSL.

This is my code in launch.json. Lots of help appreciated.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "(gdb) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Projects/CPP/helloworld/helloworld.out",
    "args": [""],
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "cwd": "/mnt/c/Users/myusername/Projects/CPP/helloworld/",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "windows": {
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "pipeTransport": {
      "pipeCwd": "",
      "pipeProgram": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe",
      "pipeArgs": ["-c"],
      "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
      "/mnt/c": "C:\\",
      "/usr": "C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\usr\\"
    }
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Does `>> ls /usr/bin/gdb` in the WSL show the file exists?

Comment: yes it does, I just accessed the WSL, typed in cd usr, cd bin and ls gdb and it shows that gdb does exist

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and finally got it to work!

Two changes:

1) Under pipeTransport, change pipeProgram:
      `"pipeProgram": "bash.exe"`

2) under SourceFileMap:
 remove `/usr`

Here is my full `launch.json` file (just replace USERNAME with yours):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

      {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/home/USERNAME/projects/helloworld/helloworld.out",
        "args": [""],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "/home/USERNAME/projects/helloworld/",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "windows": {
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
          "setupCommands": [
            {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
            }
          ]
        },
        "pipeTransport": {
          "pipeCwd": "",
          "pipeProgram": "bash.exe", 
          "pipeArgs": ["-c"],
          "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
          "/mnt/c": "c:\\",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```